# How can I change activity duration from minutes to hours?

Tags: activity

I have a client that reports activity duration in "Units" using hours. Is there a way to configure Civi to use hours? Or, would that require a custom field?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following modules to collect activity data and convert hours to minutes on the front end.

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm
https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_calculator

Answer (score 1):

When recording a new activity, the duration field indicates "minutes", but this is just a label within the form itself - activity reports will provide you with the duration column, but without indication of whether you are talking about minutes or hours, so this leaves you with two options:

1. (preferred) if you know your way into the code of the record activity form, it would be a simple question of changing the label, **OR**
2. if you feel confident with replacing all instances of the word "minutes" with "hours", you can use Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Word Replacement **TIP:** using "exact match" also refers to capitalization, so you will need to enter the word "minutes" in lower case in order for any change to take effect. If you want to switch the replacement back from hours to minutes, you will need to enter a new set of words for replacement (disabling a word replacement won't undo what you've already replaced, but it will prevent future replacements).

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Comment: Thank you for the information. I've found that Word Replacement in Civi does not work for me. I tried to change "minutes" to "hours" exact match and there is no effect on the label. Also, with this method on the original question, the field will not accept non-integer input (e.g. 1.25). Any ideas on these issues?

Comment: Hmm, I always test before offering a response and the word replacement worked for me - could it be a question of refresh? If you did refresh, what version of Civi are you on? Regarding non-integer input , I'm afraid that might require an override to the hard coded form anyway, so if you go that route, you may as well just update the label in the code as well. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Updated in code and database and all is well. Thanks for your help.